# How can I set up an automatic core dump in an Upstart script?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, upstart, ulimit, gdb

`myapp` is an application that crashes eventually. I would like to get the core dump of those crashes...

This is the upstart script I have written to achieve this. It doesn't work yet.

```
description "myupstart"

start on runlevel [2534]
stop on runlevel [!2534]

script

    ulimit -c 10000
    echo "/var/crash/core.%e.%s.%u.%g.%p.%t" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern

    cd /path/to/app
    ./myapp

end script

respawn
```

**Details:**
`myapp` works with drop of permissions. It starts as root [of course] and then switches to another username/group. Is this a problem?

The following commands work on command line if I start the application manually, but they don't work in the upstart script:

```
ulimit -c 10000
echo "/var/crash/core.%e.%s.%u.%g.%p.%t" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

Why this difference?

Comment: The bounty says "The current answer(s) are out-of-date" but actually they are no answers!

Comment: can I edit? I thought it was for answers of similar questions... that don't satisfy anymore...

Comment: No, it is ok. If you think there are similar answers that didn't worked for you, you should mention them in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try making a separate wrapper bash script with the commands between `script` and `end script` and pass that to an `exec` option in the same upstart file.

Chance are that whatever `ulimit -c 10000` does disappears by the time upstart calls `./myapp`.

Also note that it isn't quite correct to name your file "upstart script". It is a configuration file. It may happen to contain executable lines but its main purpose is to store configuration and not executable commands.

**Addendum:** I followd the same logic above, but instead of create another script, I had the idea of do `ulimit -c 10000 && ./myapp` and it worked! upstart accepted the `&&`

Comment: hummm... good idea... so I will try `ulimit -c 10000 && ./myapp` so I don't need to create another file... but the logic is the same! thanks

Comment: I don't think upstart supports joining commands with &&, it may just pass the && as another parameter to `ulimit`. Remember, the upstart file is processed by upstart and not by bash (or another shell) and anything beyond program name and parameters is unlikely to work.

Comment: "the upstart file is processed by upstart and not by bash" = COOL! but it accepted the && and it worked! thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work equally well.

```
description "myupstart"

start on runlevel [2534]
stop on runlevel [!2534]

limit core 10000 10000
chdir /path/to/myapp

pre-start script
    echo "/var/crash/core.%e.%s.%u.%g.%p.%t" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
end script

exec /path/to/app/myapp
```